# netbeans for linux java 1.6.0_32 for accumulo on Cloudera Support

Tags: java, python, netbeans, hadoop, accumulo

I am trying to find a version of netbeans for linux java 1.6.0_32 for accumulo client development on cloudera so that I can have the same environment as my collegues.

I would appreciate assistance with IDE specification and download. Development will be in Java (I hope python in the feature)

Furthermore any links to installing dependencies for accumulo and hadoop are appreciated. I have only used eclipse and and looking fowared to using netbeans.

thanks for your assistance.

Chris

Comment: Netbeans, technically, is platform independent, being written entirely in Java.  So in theory, so long as you can run Swing programs on your system, you should be able to run NetBeans.  I would find out what version your colleagues are using and download that, this will reduce the risk of inconsistencies between the project/build files.  The installation of 3rd party libraries comes down to the type of project you are using, for example, if you're using a Maven project, Netbeans can download the dependencies automatically.

Comment: If you're using Maven for your project then you shouldn't have any problems.  We currently work on a project that one developer uses IntelliJ, one uses Eclipse, and the other strictly `vim`.  There really is no dependency between the IDE and the code, so it *shouldn't* matter what IDE you are using.  I say shouldn't because I guess in theory you could be checking in artifacts related to the IDE, but that's a bad idea.